# AlpacaJS: dependency previous value

Tags: alpacajs

Is it possible to get the previously selected dependency value?

Example
**Select box 1:**
Residence Type
- House
- Apartment
- Etc...

**Select box 2:**
Service Providers
- SP1
- SP2

Select box 2 values are dependent on select box 1.  How can I get the value from select box 1 before loading the datasource for select box 2?

What I was hoping to find is that alpaca automatically pass in the caller selected value/text when using a dependency callback for loading the datasource.

Anyone else find a work-around to this issue?

Comment: I just stumbled across your post as I was searching for a solution of handle this behavior in an array object. But if you're using defined fields, it's easy the observer does the job. http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/observables.html

Comment: Thank you. We ended up using jquery form builder.